# Placeholder values in PHP cauing issues

Tags: php, placeholder

I have creating a real estate search form but for the number of bedrooms I have the fields displaying Min and Max until a user inputs the numbers. I do this using this code;

```
<input type="text" name="room_no_min" id="room_no_min" value="Min" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Min'" onFocus="if (this.value == 'Min') {this.value=''};" class="min_input">

<input type="text" name="room_no_max" id="room_no_max" value="Max" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Max'" onFocus="if (this.value == 'Max') {this.value=''};" class="min_input">
```

But if nothing is inputted and the results are displayed the Min box appears empty whilst the Max box continues to correctly show Max. To display the results I use this code;

```
    //check bedrooms
if(!empty($_GET["room_no_min"]) && is_numeric($_GET["room_no_min"])){
     $query[] = "'No_Bedrooms' >= '".$_GET["room_no_min"]."'";
     $room_min_val = $_GET["room_no_min"];
}
    if(!empty($_GET["room_no_max"])){
     $query[] = "'No_Bedrooms' <= '".$_GET["room_no_max"]."'";
     $room_max_val = $_GET["room_no_max"];
}
```

followed by

```
<input type="text" name="room_no_min" id="room_no_min" value="<?php echo $room_min_val?>" value="Min" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Min'" onFocus="if (this.value == 'Min') {this.value=''};" class="min_input">

<input type="text" name="room_no_max" id="room_no_max" value="<?php echo $room_max_val?>" value="Max" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Max'" onFocus="if (this.value == 'Max') {this.value=''};" class="min_input">
```

I know the place where the problem is likely to be is the is_Numeric part of screening the Min value but can't seem to figure out how to make it work.

Any solutions please?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use HTML tag placeholder?

```
<input type="text" name="room_no_min" id="room_no_min" placeholder="Min" class="min_input">
```

This will save you a lot of headaches.

Comment: From what I understand for IE the placeholder tag only works with IE10 so the boxes show up blank for older versions.

Comment: There are good polyfills for input[placeholder], e.g. https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder